# SSH public key will not send to server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keygen

I have read through a number of sites to no avail.  So I need to see if someone else can see what I am doing wrong.

I am using ubuntu 18.  Here is ssh -v output:

```
debug1: Found key in /home/leithner/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:5nOs3DjENMsvwbU2jHNE2GOv6u/1L5TyFCgc3zPYNDM /home/leithner/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leithner/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leithner/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leithner/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password

ssh with port output:
Host '[elm.pa...]:53999' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/leithner/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:5nOs3DjENMsvwbU2jHNE2GOv6u/1L5TyFCgc3zPYNDM /home/leithner/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leithner/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leithner/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leithner/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password

From /var/log/auth.log file:
Aug 19 14:44:55 birch sshd[22485]: Accepted publickey for leithner from 129.244.22.126 port 57912 ssh2: RSA SHA256:qLTekbB8a22YWHqRHPZjVSJ0dNEHTSoI3nFN97PEyuc
Aug 19 14:44:55 birch sshd[22485]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user leithner by (uid=0)
Aug 19 14:44:55 birch systemd-logind[1059]: New session 38875 of user leithner.
Aug 19 14:45:01 birch CRON[22582]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Aug 19 14:43:44 birch sshd[22367]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user leithner
Aug 19 14:44:55 birch sshd[22485]: Accepted publickey for leithner from 129.244.22.126 port 57912 ssh2: RSA SHA256:qLTekbB8a22YWHqRHPZjVSJ0dNEHTSoI3nFN97PEyuc
Aug 19 14:44:55 birch sshd[22485]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user leithner by (uid=0)
Aug 19 14:44:55 birch systemd-logind[1059]: New session 38875 of user leithner.
Aug 19 14:45:01 birch CRON[22582]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 19 14:45:01 birch CRON[22582]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Aug 19 14:47:25 birch sshd[22567]: Received disconnect from 129.244.22.126 port 57912:11: disconnected by user



.ssh directory 
directory permissions are drwx------  2 leithner users  4096 Aug 19 15:27 .ssh

leithner@birch:~/.ssh$ ls -l
total 20
-rw------- 1 leithner users  394 Aug 19 14:43 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 leithner users   26 Aug 19 15:23 config
-rw------- 1 leithner users 1675 Aug 19 15:26 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 leithner users  396 Aug 19 15:26 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 leithner users  888 Aug 19 15:28 known_hosts

.ssh directory on server
directory permissions on server are: drwx------  2 leithner ppa    4096 Aug 19 14:27  .ssh



leithner@elm:~/.ssh$ ls -l
total 20
-rw------- 1 leithner ppa  396 Aug 19 14:27 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 leithner ppa   85 Aug 19 14:23 config
-rw------- 1 leithner ppa 1823 Aug 19 13:36 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 leithner ppa  394 Aug 19 13:36 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 leithner ppa 1992 Aug 19 14:20 known_hosts
```

I created keys with ssh-keygen and copied them to server with ssh-copy-id leithner@elm

Ssh is requesting a password instead of using keys.

```
 ssh -p 53997 elm
 leithner@elm's password:
```

Here is the auth.log on server:

Aug 22 11:59:03 elm sshd[2081934]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/leithner
Aug 22 11:59:12 elm sshd[2081934]: Accepted password for leithner from 129.244.22.120 port 43340 ssh2

What permissions should my directory be:

**Solved:
The issues is my home directory was 775 it needs to be 755.
drwxr-xr-x 24 leithner  ppa   4096 Aug 22 12:55 leithner**

Any ideas would be appreciated, I have redone the keys multiple times.

Comment: What problem is?

Comment: Try using another key type than `rsa`, i.e. `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`. From the logs, it appears that `id_rsa` is never tried.

Comment: You showed us some log from birch, apparently the client, but any log entries relevant to your problem will be in the log on the _server_, apparently elm. (@Panki)

Comment: Thank you all for help.  The issues was my home directory had 775 permissions instead of 755.  I changed this and now it works.  I found the error in the auth.log file on server.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is either

1. Permissions (most of whom seem to be correct).

   The only ones that seem to be wrong are the `*.pub` keys. To be sure, you could `chmod` the folder and keys again. Also, `stat --format '%a' <dir or file>` will give you the numerical value of the `chmod`. That way you can see if the permissions of the folder and files are correct.

   *Note that the `chmod` permissions below (which are correct) need to be the same on both host and guest.*

```
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys # yes, this one needs specific permissions, too
```

2. Erroneous copying method

   It should be good enough the way you did it, but it might be better to copy the public keys to the host by using `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub remoteuser@HOST.IP.ADDR.ESS`. Note that for this to work, the permissions need to be correct, or else it will fail/prompt for a password each time.

Please post the output of the SSH without the `-v` flag. That might give us a better idea of what's happening.